# How to watch public directory in Vite project for hot-reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

I have a react project configured with Vite.
Hot reload works great, but I use `react-i18next` for multiple language support and this is my structure:

```
public
  -> en
    -> translation.json
  -> ru
    -> translation.json
```

When I change the `translation.json` files, Vite doesn't watch it, and I have to refresh the page to see the changes.

Is there a way to tell Vite to watch all the files in the `public` directory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 2023:** You should read and use the answer by @ErickLima to avoid full-reload.

---

You can achieve that with a plugin.

*I made a mistake on my first answer, it should be a `full-reload` event and not a `update` event*

```js
export default function CustomHmr() {
    return {
      name: 'custom-hmr',
      enforce: 'post',
      // HMR
      handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {
        if (file.endsWith('.json')) {
          console.log('reloading json file...');
  
          server.ws.send({
            type: 'full-reload',          
            path: '*'
          });
        }
      },
    }
}
```

then add the plugin in `vite.config.js` :

```
{
  plugins: [
    CustomHmr()   <---  custom plugin
  ]
}
```

Check the example published on Stackblitz:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-react-i18n

#### Result Illustration

[image]

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. Also I'm using Typescript and the return type  of the custom plugin doesn't match to what Vite accepts in the plugins array which is ```Plugin```

Comment: @TwoHorses I updated my answer, you will find a Gituhb repo with full working example.

Comment: Thanks this works. One question, I notice that when I update a json file, the entire window is reloaded. But when you just change a component content, it only updates that part of the app, without full reload. Is that impossible to achieve?

Comment: This should be in the official documentation.

Comment: @TwoHorses, just add `import type { Plugin } from 'vite';` at the top of your typescript file and then type the exported function as a `Plugin` like this: `export default function CustomHmr(): Plugin {}` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

I've modified flydev's answer so that it can hot-reload the i18n-dependent components without reloading the whole page. (Currently using in a typescript project)

```js
import { PluginOption } from "vite";

export default function I18nHotReload(): PluginOption {
  return {
    name: 'i18n-hot-reload',
    handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {
      if (file.includes('locales') && file.endsWith('.json')) {
        console.log('Locale file updated')
        server.ws.send({
          type: "custom",
          event: "locales-update",
        });
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Then adding it to the vite's plugins:

```js
plugins: [
    ...,
    i18nHotReload(),
]
```

And then adding the listener anywhere your code can reach (I'm using it in the i18n initial config file)

```js
if (import.meta.hot) {
  import.meta.hot.on('locales-update', () => {
    i18n.reloadResources().then(() => {
      i18n.changeLanguage(i18n.language)
    })
  })
}
```

> `i18n.reloadResources()` alone doesn't trigger the translations hot reload

Comment: much more elegant solution, been searching for this :)

Comment: This solution is good